# how can i run "Stop" after I click Begin twice in a row successfully?

Tags: javascript

After I click Begin(in form-input label) twice in a row, I run "Stop" and it doesn't work. why it doesn't work and how can i run "Stop" after I click Begin twice in a row successfully?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num=5;
    function goBack()
    {
        window.history.back();
    }
    function clock(){

        document.getElementById("xxx").value=num;
        num=num-1;
    }
    var i=setInterval(clock,1000);
    function Stop()
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
    function Begin()
    {
        i=setInterval(clock,1000);
    }
</script>
<body>
    welcome to test!
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="xxx" height="20px">
        <input type="button" value="go back" onclick="goBack()">
        <input type="button" value="bein" onclick="Begin()">
        <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="Stop()">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read inline comment below

```js
var num=5;
function goBack()
{
    window.history.back();
}
function clock(){

    document.getElementById("xxx").value=num;
    num=num-1;
}
var i=setInterval(clock,1000);
function Stop()
{
    clearInterval(i);
}
function Begin()
{
    //
    //
    // CLEAR interval each time you begin, obviously
    clearInterval(i);
    i=setInterval(clock,1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    welcome to test!
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="xxx" height="20px">
        <input type="button" value="go back" onclick="goBack()">
        <input type="button" value="bein" onclick="Begin()">
        <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="Stop()">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a variable like I did to limit the number of time the function begin will run

```js
    var num=5;
    var count=0;
    function goBack()
    {
        window.history.back();
    }
    function clock(){

        document.getElementById("xxx").value=num;
        num=num-1;
    }
    var i;
    function Stop()
    {
        clearInterval(i);
        count=0;
    }
    function Begin()
    { 
        
        if(count==0)
        i=setInterval(clock,1000);
        count++;
    }
```

```html
    welcome to test!
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="xxx" height="20px">
        <input type="button" value="go back" onclick="goBack()">
        <input type="button" value="bein" onclick="Begin()">
        <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="Stop()">
    </form>
```